# How to allow all to use mint function of aptos coin

Tags: aptos

How to allow anyone use mint function of my coin in aptos?

Now i have this code

```
    public entry fun mint(account: &signer, dst_addr: address, amount: u64) {
        aptos_framework::managed_coin::mint<Coin>(account, dst_addr, amount);
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Aptos is moving away from Coin standard, Fungbile Asset is the successor to Coin.

Checkout the [fungible asset tutorial](https://aptos.dev/tutorials/your-first-fungible-asset#step-433-managing-a-coin) on minting and transferring a fungible asset you create.